# Does Swap Space Use Real RAM To Keep It On?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ram, swap

I would like to know if having swap space, uses RAM/Memory to keep the swap space 'active', even though the swap space is virtual RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from Ubuntu website

> Swap space is the area on a hard disk which is part of the Virtual
>   Memory of your machine, which is a combination of accessible physical
>   memory (RAM) and the swap space. Swap space temporarily holds memory
>   pages that are inactive. Swap space is used when your system decides
>   that it needs physical memory for active processes and there is
>   insufficient unused physical memory available. If the system happens
>   to need more memory resources or space, inactive pages in physical
>   memory are then moved to the swap space therefore freeing up that
>   physical memory for other uses.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

So in short swap is place in harddisk used to store RAM data.